# Solaris services type status

Tags: solaris, services

There are following service states in Solaris:

> 1. degraded – The instance is running or available to run, but is functioning at a limited capacity.
> 2. disabled – The instance is not enabled and is not running or available to run.
> 3. maintenance – The instance is enabled but not able to run. The instance might be transitioning through the maintenance state because
>      an administrative action has not yet completed. Otherwise,
>      administrative action is required to resolve the problem.
> 4. offline – The instance is enabled but not running or available to run. For example, if the dependencies of an enabled service are not
>      satisfied, the service is kept in the offline state.
> 5. online – The instance is enabled and running or available to run. The online state is the expected operating state for a correctly
>      configured service instance with all dependencies satisfied.
> 6. uninitialized – This state is the initial state for all services.

I want to understand the 'uninitialized' state. Someone, please explain this state. Does this mean that the service is installed and enabled but it is not yet enabled. Or the service is in disabled state.

Comment: I don't know if it can be made clearer than that. It's possible that the inclusion of the "uninitialized" state is just confusing. The service will immediately be moved to some other state when `svc.startd` starts. Are you having an issue where you see a service in this state?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the man page from e.g. `svcs(1)`, the explanation for these states is in the man page `smf(5)`, so just call:

```
man -s 5 smf
```